# Toggle the masking and unmasking of a TextBox using a CheckBox

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, textbox, masking

I have a `TextBox`, which has a `CheckBox` operation to mask the containing text.  This works with the following code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    TextBox14.PasswordChar = "*"
End Sub
```

It works well, but I want to also be able to uncheck the`CheckBox` and then have the recognizable text return.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by simply setting the `PasswordChar` property back to a null character, like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        TextBox14.PasswordChar = "*"c
    Else
        TextBox14.PasswordChar = ControlChars.NullChar
    End If
End Sub
```

The `CheckedChanged` event occurs every time the `Checked` property changes.  So, when the user unchecks the `CheckBox`, it will raise that event too, so you need to check to see whether or not the control is currently checked.

Answer (score 2):

The docos actually state:

> The character used to mask characters entered in a single-line TextBox
>   control. Set the value of this property to 0 (character value) if you
>   do not want the control to mask characters as they are typed. Equals 0
>   (character value) by default.

Found here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar(v=vs.110).aspx

In VB.NET, that would be easiest done by setting `PasswordChar` to `vbNullChar`.

Comment: +1 Ah, good point.  I was thinking at first it was a string, not a character.

Answer (score 0):

I found just toggling the password character wasn't enough. In my case I was masking a connection string. With the lack of spaces in my text I had an issue going back and forth. My text would be cut off and wasn't wrapping properly.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim beforeText As String = TextBox1.Text

    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.PasswordChar = IIf(CheckBox1.Checked, Convert.ToChar(0), "*"c)
    TextBox1.Text = beforeText
End Sub
```

I imagine if you used a font like Console this would not be a problem as all character widths are constant.